# How to plot the first difference of a time series

Tags: r, difference

I know this is pretty basic but I can't seem to get the code to work.  I have a time series data set and I am trying to make it stationary by taking the first difference but I don't know what code to use to do that in R. The data is not in a library; I just imported it as a csv file.

What I've tried is `plot(diff(data), type="o", main="first difference")` and I get the error

> Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : 
>       non-numeric argument to binary operator`

I am new to R so I have no idea what this means.

```
> dput(hotel)
structure(list(Month = 1:168, Occupancy = c(501L, 488L, 504L, 
578L, 545L, 632L, 728L, 725L, 585L, 542L, 480L, 530L, 518L, 489L, 
528L, 599L, 572L, 659L, 739L, 758L, 602L, 587L, 497L, 558L, 555L, 
523L, 532L, 623L, 598L, 683L, 774L, 780L, 609L, 604L, 531L, 592L, 
578L, 543L, 565L, 648L, 615L, 697L, 785L, 830L, 645L, 643L, 551L, 
606L, 585L, 553L, 576L, 665L, 656L, 720L, 826L, 838L, 652L, 661L, 
584L, 644L, 623L, 553L, 599L, 657L, 680L, 759L, 878L, 881L, 705L, 
684L, 577L, 656L, 645L, 593L, 617L, 686L, 679L, 773L, 906L, 934L, 
713L, 710L, 600L, 676L, 645L, 602L, 601L, 709L, 706L, 817L, 930L, 
983L, 745L, 735L, 620L, 698L, 665L, 626L, 649L, 740L, 729L, 824L, 
937L, 994L, 781L, 759L, 643L, 728L, 691L, 649L, 656L, 735L, 748L, 
837L, 995L, 1040L, 809L, 793L, 692L, 763L, 723L, 655L, 658L, 
761L, 768L, 885L, 1067L, 1038L, 812L, 790L, 692L, 782L, 758L, 
709L, 715L, 788L, 794L, 893L, 1046L, 1075L, 812L, 822L, 714L, 
802L, 748L, 731L, 748L, 827L, 788L, 937L, 1076L, 1125L, 840L, 
864L, 717L, 813L, 811L, 732L, 745L, 844L, 833L, 935L, 1110L, 
1124L, 868L, 860L, 762L, 877L)), .Names = c("Month", "Occupancy"
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-168L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(Month = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), Occupancy = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("Month", "Occupancy")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Can you provide a small subset of your data to help troubleshoot? It looks like your data might contain non-numeric values, which is going throw an error whenever you attempt binary operators (i.e. addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, exponentiation)

Comment: I've been trying all different kinds of data sets. They have different formatting but the x variable is either a year (1920), or a year with a month (1920-01), for example. And then the y variable is just a number.

Comment: Why did you take a screen shot and not just copy/paste the text? (that's a genuine question. I see this happen from time to time, but I can't figure out why people do it)

Comment: Lol, I haven't posted on here much. I didn't know if the formatting would stay intact or if it would be hard to read, so I just went the safe route.

Comment: Ah. When we ask for data and/or code it's usually so we can use it on our end. Posting a photo means we'll have to transcribe it, which is a chore. Sometimes a screen shot can convey something a straight text drop can't, but that's more the exception. In this case the optimum would be if you posted whatever you get when you run `dput(data)`. Highlight the code and press the { } button in the edit window to format.

Comment: Ok, I posted my output from `dput(hotel)`, and I removed the screenshot because this is for a different data set

Comment: Any idea why there are L's after all my data points?? When I look at the data in excel there are no L's. I'm guessing that's the non-numeric argument it's warning me about

Comment: There's no need to understand the `dput()` output. It is correct. The `L` stands for long integer. See my answer for a guess of what you want.

Answer (score 2):

#### ts

The problem is that you have an R data frame

```
class(employment)
## [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

and while it is possible to work with that representation it would be easier if you used an R time series object such as a `ts` object or a `zoo` object (from the zoo package).

Below we convert the data frame to a `ts` object and then take the first difference of its log and plot it.  Since the times are 1, 2, 3, ... and that is the default we don't have to specify the times when creating the `ts` object `empts`

```
empts <- ts(employment$employmentW)
plot(diff(log(empts)))
```

(continued after image)

[image]

#### data.frame

If you did want to keep the data frame representation then try this.  Note that diff reduces the length by one so we remove the first element of Month to keep the x and y parts the same length so that we are plotting the first difference of the log against 2, 3, 4, ... which is likely what is wanted.  With the time series representation this is all automatically taken care of but not with the data frame representation so we have to do it manually.

```
plot(diff(log(employmentW)) ~ Month[-1], employment, type = "l")
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you help me with the code to remove the seasonality? I have to fit an ARMA model and I see that the ACF peaks every 12 lags.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the tidyverse approach.

The original data:

```
head(hotel)
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   Month Occupancy
#   <int>     <int>
# 1     1       501
# 2     2       488
# 3     3       504
# 4     4       578
# 5     5       545
# 6     6       632
```

Calculate differences in occupancy from month to month:

```
library(dplyr)
hotel_diff <- 
  hotel %>%
  mutate(Difference = Occupancy - lag(Occupancy)) %>%
  na.omit() # to remove the first row which has an NA

head(hotel_diff)
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   Month Occupancy Difference
#   <int>     <int>      <int>
# 1     2       488        -13
# 2     3       504         16
# 3     4       578         74
# 4     5       545        -33
# 5     6       632         87
# 6     7       728         96
```

Plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(hotel_diff, aes(Month, Difference)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

If you're new to R, I strongly suggest you skip the base-R data-wrangling and plotting functions and go straight to tidyverse packages such as `dplyr` and `ggplot2`. Your life will be much easier. There'a great free book available on this topic here: [R for Data Science.](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/)

Comment: Thank you. I see that the difference plot still isn't stationary so I selected a different data set that will be stationary as the first difference. Here is the error I get when I do what you did `> library(dplyr)
> snow_diff <- 
+ snow %>%
+ mutate(difference = snow-lag(snow)) %>%
+ na.omit()
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column difference must be length 63 (the number of rows) or one, not 2`

Answer (score 1):

Streamlined, base-R code (using `log()` since you requested it in a later, nearly identical post):

```
plot(diff(log(hotel$Occupancy)), type="o", main="first difference")
```